# Convert Date format into bigint format in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How can I convert date format into bigint format in postgresql?
for eg: '2018-08-20' to '20180820'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
postgres=# create table dttest ( dt date ) ;
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into dttest values ( '2018-08-20' ) ;
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from dttest;
     dt     
------------
 2018-08-20
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_char( dt, 'YYYYMMDD' ) from dttest ; 
 to_char  
----------
 20180820
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

`TO_CHAR` and other date/time formatting [is documented here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

Oh, and if you actually do want to cast to `bigint`:

```
select to_char( dt, 'YYYYMMDD' )::bigint from dttest ;
```

Comment: Thank sir and i got the new option too from your answer= select to_char( now(), 'YYYYMMDD' )::bigint

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(extract(epoch from '2018-08-20'::date) as bigint);
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer for the OP's question. But a quite useful answer for someone wanting a `bigint` instead of the floating point value `epoch` ends up returning.